# Is there a php way to replicate a value multiple time in array, better than cycle?

Tags: php, arrays

I need to create an array with N variable instances of the same value.

The obvious solution is a `for()` cycle that appends the value to an array.

I wonder if it exists some more efficient solution, maybe a native function, for instance:

```
$var=1
DO_REPLICA($var,3);
```

the result should be:

```
[1,1,1]
```

Comment: A more elegant solution may be [`array_fill`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill). Efficieny I'm not so certain about, since there's no way to escape a loop (all array function internally loop the array), but it's not something you need to worry about. Differences would be minor.

Comment: `array_pad` also comes to mind. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pad.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`array_fill`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill)

> Fill an array with values

```php
$var = 1;
$arr = array_fill(0, 3, $var);
```

The above code will create an array with `$var` from index **0** to the **3**'th index

[Try it online!](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/62157e043b50182ec32fb5da83f25390c9593be6)